# Plain text value for CC Page Label valueRT field in B2B Commerce

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, b2b-commerce, cloudcraze

I'm trying to insert a plain text string into the `valueRT` field of a CC Page Label item in B2B Commerce Cloud Version 4.11

Ideally, I'm looking for a way to do this through the Lightning interface. Selecting the entire entry in the `valueRT` fields rich-text editor and clicking the "remove formatting" icon still leaves the string wrapped in a `<p>` element when I check the value for the field in the `CCRZ.pagevars.pageLabels` object in the browser console.

I tried re-enabling the plain `value` field, but our implementation does require rich formatting for non-technical employees in some CC Page Labels, so I cannot turn off `valueRT`; as long as `valueRT` is enabled, it will automatically overwrite whatever is entered in `value`.

I'll probably fall back to stripping tags/formatting out of the output on the front-end, but (since all the unmodified, out-of-the box `CCRZ.pagevars.pageLabel` values are **not** wrapped in HTML), I feel like there's likely a way to enter the value plain text in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unrelated to CloudCraze, it's a Lightning Experience related issue. If you create page labels using Lightning Experience mode, they will be wrapped in a `<p>` element when they render. Toggle into Classic Mode and create your page labels there instead.

Comment: Thanks! Just in case anyone (like me) had never toggled to Classic, here's the Salesforce Documentation on it: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000337767&type=1&mode=1

Answer (score 0):

Switch to classic mode ,Try adding the value to the valueRT of CC Page Label and save it.